# MSGraph Delete Group Push Notifications: Wrong changeType on Delete Events

Tags: azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api, azure-ad-graph-api

When I perform a deletion of a group in the Azure AD portal and I have set my push notification changeType = 'updated,deleted', the push notification is received within 10-15 seconds as expected with the correct resource ID of the group that I deleted, but the changeType = 'updated'. See the actual event received below:

```
{
   "value":[
      {
         "changeType":"updated",
         "clientState":"<<redacted>>",
         "resource":"Groups/f0a5993b-5c2d-49cc-bb2f-8cb0060fef8e",
         "resourceData":{
            "@odata.type":"#Microsoft.Graph.Group",
            "@odata.id":"Groups/f0a5993b-5c2d-49cc-bb2f-8cb0060fef8e",
            "id":"f0a5993b-5c2d-49cc-bb2f-8cb0060fef8e",
            "organizationId":"<<redacted>>",
            "eventTime":"2018-11-22T01:47:00.2455823Z",
            "sequenceNumber":636784480202455800
         },
         "subscriptionExpirationDateTime":"2018-11-24T18:13:08.914+00:00",
         "subscriptionId":"d850b120-19bb-4291-b9c4-845ea04dd38d",
         "tenantId":"<<readacted>>"
      }
   ]
}
```

Upon processing this request, there is no way to determine that the current group resource has been DELETED. Can someone on the Graph API team please look into/resolve?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is likely that the group you deleted was an [Office 365 group](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/learn-about-office-365-groups-b565caa1-5c40-40ef-9915-60fdb2d97fa2). When Office 365 groups are deleted, they are soft-deleted, which is represented as an `updated` event, rather than a `deleted` change type. You'll notice the same behavior when users are deleted, if you subscribe to `updated,deleted` for `users`, which also support soft-deletion.

(A soft-deleted Office 365 group can be [restored within 30 days](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office365/admin/create-groups/restore-deleted-group). In contrast, other group types get permanently deleted immediately and cannot be restored.)

If you're using [delta query](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/concepts/delta_query_overview) in concert with change notifications (a typical pattern is to use the `updated` change event as a trigger to poll for more changes with delta query), the soft-deletion of a group would look like this:

```
GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/groups/delta?$deltatoken=1yN...
```

```json
{
    "@odata.context": "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/$metadata#groups",
    "@odata.deltaLink": "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/groups/delta?$deltatoken=1yN...",
    "value": [
        {
            "id": "0ed62d01-7c00-4866-9220-74fdd034eea7",
            "@removed": {
                "reason": "changed"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

When a soft-deleted Office 365 group gets permanently deleted (either naturally, after the 30 days pass, or manually, because someone [permanently deleted it](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office365/admin/create-groups/restore-deleted-group?view=o365-worldwide#permanently-delete-an-office-365-group)), you will get the expected `deleted` change type in the subscription:

```json
{
    "value": [
        {
            "changeType": "deleted",
            "resource": "Groups/0ed62d01-7c00-4866-9220-74fdd034eea7",
            "resourceData": ...
            ...
        }
    ]
}
```

In the delta query for groups, the group's permanent deletion will be represented as follows:

```
GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/groups/delta?$deltatoken=1yN...
```

```json
{
    "@odata.context": "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/$metadata#groups",
    "@odata.deltaLink": "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/groups/delta?$deltatoken=1yN...",
    "value": [
        {
            "id": "0ed62d01-7c00-4866-9220-74fdd034eea7",
            "@removed": {
                "reason": "deleted"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

**Other info**

Office 365 groups can be identified in Microsoft Graph by their `groupTypes` attribute, which will contain the string `Unified` if it's an Office 365 group.

```
GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/groups/{id}?$select=id,displayName,groupTypes
```

```json
{
    "@odata.context": "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/$metadata#groups(id,groupTypes)/$entity",
    "id": "0ed62d01-7c00-4866-9220-74fdd034eea7",
    "displayName": "My Office 365 group",
    "groupTypes": [
        "Unified"
    ]
}
```

Soft-deleted groups can be listed with Microsoft Graph:

```
GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/directory/deletedItems/microsoft.graph.group
```

To permanently delete a soft-deleted object using Microsoft Graph:

```
DELETE https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/directory/deletedItems/{id}
```

Comment: Thank you for this outstanding reply and full explanation. I appreciate the time and effort you put in for this and I now understand this fully.  I wish Microsoft's own documentation was as thorough on this topic.  Happy holidays sir!

Comment: philippe-signoret: Quick question for you sir.  I've used the methodology you've outlined and it works well but here is something I'm hoping you can help implement at Microsoft ASAP.  When you want to initiate a delta on a group, can we have the option to make the starting point as NOW rather than having to cycle through all the changes before being able to obtain the most up-to-date deltaToken at the very end to be "caught up".  Why would this be helpful?  Let's say you create a group and sync the changes at same time, there's no need to have to cycle thru all records...

Comment: ...all that is needed at this point is the deltaToken to track changes from @now forward.  This would save tons and tons of processing I'm sure on MS servers, especially on large groups with hundreds or thousands of members.  It would make the deltaQuery more usuable too.  Less logic would have to be written if all you care about is future changes rather than all changes since group creation.  Please help and advise on how possible this could be implemented.  Again, I think it would cut down on the likelihood of high loads from those using this feature.  Thanks in advance!

Comment: @tfrancois You can already do this! In you initial delta request, add the query parameter `$deltaToken=latest`: `GET .../groups/delta?$filter=...&$deltaToken=latest`, and the response will only contain a `$deltaLink` as of "now". See the note in the docs: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/delta-query-overview#use-delta-query-to-track-changes-in-a-resource-collection

Comment: SIr that is OUTSTANDING!  This must have been added recently because I swore I went through all the documentation on delta query prior to my reply.  Nevertheless this is EXACTLY what I was looking for!  Very excting.  Thank you!

Comment: Any chance support could be added for expand=memberOf to user delta change events/notifications. This way instead of having to create notifications for both users and groups, if a change to user membership occurs, there would be no need to track events or require notifications from both the user and the group in question! Again, this makes the events more efficient and reduces load on the back-end and processing logic on client side. FYI, currently, when I add the expand=memberOf to my user delta change requests, I get NO errors(!) but it seems to be ignored. Any thoughts?